# видео в модальном окне bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

в модальном окне содержится тег video который проигрывает файл, но при нажатии на кнопку закрыть модальное окно скрывается а видео продолжает играть. кто знает как это исправить?

Comment: На закрытие окна нужно повесить [остановку видео](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20005842/8416715).